# How does OWIN work?

Tags: functional-programming, owin

I'm reading the OWIN 1.0 spec at http://owin.org/spec/owin-1.0.0.html and just can't wrap my head around how it works. I've downloaded Katana source, but that's huge and didn't help any. I'm familiar with the somewhat standard way of having a project/assembly with interfaces only, which allows to integrate two projects without direct regencies. But I can't understand how the web server will call into the web app with only Func<> and Action<> definitions.

Answer (score 4):

OWIN boils down to two things:

1) an "environment" dictionary

2) a method that processes requests and sends responses.

For #1, this is just a property bag that gives you access to the request headers, request stream, response headers, response stream and server data.  Think of this as your HttpContext for ASP.NET or HttpListenerContext for System.Net.HttpListener.  In fact, in more recent builds of Katana (https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/, which is an open source implementation from the ASP.NET team, there have been improvements (more to come) to simplify this down to an easier to use object model, including an [OwinRequest](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/OwinRequest.cs), [OwinResponse](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/OwinResponse.cs), and [IOwinContext](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/IOwinContext.cs).

For #2, this is often called the "AppFunc" and the signature is:

```
using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;
```

This signature is used for "Middleware" that is in a pipeline of request handlers or it can be the end application which is generating HTML, is a WebAPI, etc.

In Katana, there is a class you can inherit from that simplifies this signature to consume the IOwinContext I mentioned previously.  Take at look at [OwinMiddlware](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/OwinMiddleware.cs)

You can also read this article which gives an overview of the Katana/OWIN effort: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana

Answer (score 0):

OWIN just defines how the web server and web application will talk to each other. Your application must implement one side of this contact, the other side which connects to the web server must be provided by installing a NuGet package specific to the web server. There is one for IIS, one for self hosting (stand alone application) etc.